# Statistical sampling from a vector

Tags: r, simulation

I have written a function/script to simulate data for sample size estimation. The following code samples from a vector of generated values with varying numbers of sample sizes and then concatenates means and standard deviations for a number of simulations.

I am using nested loops but would like to vectorize the code for efficiency and am wondering if anyone could suggest some optimizations.

```
library(MCMCglmm)
library(tidyverse)

Est <- function(n, mean, sd, lower, upper, samp_min, samp_max, samp_int, nsim){

        Data <- round(rtnorm(n, mean, sd, lower, upper), digits = 0) # Create a vector to sample from

        Samp_size <- seq(samp_min, samp_max, samp_int) # Create vector of sample sizes

        # Set up enpty results data frames
        Results_samp <- data.frame()
        Results <- data.frame()

        for(i in 1:nsim){ ## Loop through number of simulations

                for (j in seq_along(Samp_size)) { # Loop through sample sizes
                     SUS_Score <- sample(Data, Samp_size[j], replace = TRUE)
                     Nsubj <- Samp_size[j]
                     Mean <- mean(SUS_Score, na.rm = TRUE)
                     SD <- sd(SUS_Score, na.rm = TRUE)
                     Results_samp <- rbind(Results_samp, 
                                      data.frame(
                                              Nsubj,
                                              Mean,
                                              SD))
                }
             Results <- rbind(Results, Results_samp) 
             Results_samp <- data.frame()
        }

       Results %>%
               arrange(Nsubj)
}

Sims <- Est(n = 1000, mean = 55, sd = 37, lower = 0, upper = 100, samp_min = 5, samp_max = 35, samp_int = 5, nsim = 1000)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite good. Simulations is hard to vectorize. The largest slowdown here is the repeated calling of `rbind` in loop. It is faster to crate list of vectors and concatenate the results at the end. So  I edited the necessary parts:

```
Est3 <- function(n, mean, sd, lower, upper, samp_min, samp_max, samp_int, nsim) {
  Data <- round(rtnorm(n, mean, sd, lower, upper), digits = 0)
  Samp_size <- seq(samp_min, samp_max, samp_int)
  Results <- list() # crate emty list
  for (i in 1:nsim) {
    Results_samp <- list() # crate emty list
    for (j in seq_along(Samp_size)) {
      Nsubj <- Samp_size[j]
      SUS_Score <- sample(Data, Nsubj, replace = TRUE)
      Mean <- mean(SUS_Score, na.rm = TRUE)
      SD <- sd(SUS_Score, na.rm = TRUE)
      Results_samp[[j]] <- c(Nsubj, Mean, SD) # add values to list
    }
    Results[[i]] <- Reduce(rbind, Results_samp) # convert list to matrix and add to main list
  }
  Results <- Reduce(rbind, Results) # 'rbind' list of matrices
  Results <- as.data.frame(Results, row.names = F) # convert to data.frame
  colnames(Results) <- c('Nsubj', 'Mean', 'SD') # add names
  Results %>% arrange(Nsubj)
}
```